# Showing a vertical line for every highlighted point with RolloverModifier SciChart

Tags: scichart

I have a SciChart surface with multiple series.

I'm using a RolloverModifier with DrawVerticalLine set to True, so when I roll over a a point a vertical line is drawn through the point with a numeric value shown down by the axis.

The rollover modifier also highlights the nearest points on other series and shows labels for them. I was asked if it's possible to draw the vertical lines for these points as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, the RolloverModifier in SciChart WPF only draws one line.

Long answer: it's possible to override the RolloverModifier and draw whatever you want to the screen.

Have a look at this article on [Creating a Custom RolloverModifier](http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17235/32/custom-chartmodifiers---part-1---creating-a-custom-rollover-modifier) which might show some pointers.